# Change the default output folder for a java command when executed by php

Tags: java, php, joomla

I am trying to run a java command like this in a PHP Joomla Component. It works, however, the files generated from the command are written to /administrator and I want them to be written to the location where the Java command resides ie. /administrator/com_mycomponent/java/MyJavaApp.jar

```
            //run the command
            $javaCommand = "$javaCommand -jar $keyGeneratorFile $appName";
            $response = exec($javaCommand);

            if(empty($response)) {
                JError::raiseError(500, "Key Generation failed for command: $javaCommand");
            }
```

What can I do?  Is there some sort of option I can use with the java command?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the java program you can use the solutions discussed in following question:

[Get location from where the Java code is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682194/get-location-from-where-the-java-code-is-executed)

Comment: I solved this by changing the java app to take an output directory as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script that first changes to the directory you want and then runs the command.  Then call exec on that script.